# Inserting into postgres via psycopg2 returning syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to insert data into a postgres table using variables. Having looked at other answers on this topic it seemed pretty straightforward, however I am getting a syntax error from python before I even get a chance to insert it into the database

The execute statement I am using:

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO "public"."catalogue_product" ("id","structure","upc","title","slug","description","rating","date_created","date_updated","is_discountable","parent_id","product_class_id","collection_id","multiplier","dimension","feat1","feat10","feat2","feat3","feat4","feat5","feat6","feat7","feat8","feat9","image_url","price","short_name","sku") VALUES (nextval'catalogue_product_id_seq'::regclass),'standalone',NULL,%s,'noslug',%s,NULL,current_timestamp,current_timestamp,TRUE,NULL,NULL,NULL,'2.2',%s,'','','','','','','','','','',%s,%s,%s,%s)""", (name, desc, dimension, imageurl, price, shortname, sku))
```

All parenthesis and quotes match as they should as far as I can see.

What could be causing this?

edit: As per an answer below, I switched to using tripple quotes (and edited the code above to reflect) which does seem to help, but I still get an error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'standalone'"
LINE 1: ...ES (nextval'catalogue_product_id_seq'::regclass), 'standalon...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `)` that closes the `VALUES` list too early:

```
... ::regclass),'standalone' ...
          THIS^
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! Not sure how I missed something so obvious.